# PHPSECLIB call to undefined function crypt_random_string()

Tags: php, phpseclib

I'm trying to upload a file to sftp server using phpseclib library. Here's the code I've written

```
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib0.3.5');
    $fileName = "sImg3.jpeg";
    $fileData = file_get_contents($fileName);
    $b64Data = base64_encode($fileData);

    // upload the file to ftp server
    include('Net/SFTP.php');
    include_once('include/config.php'); // contains sftp connection details

    $sftp = new Net_SFTP($ftpHost);
    if (!$sftp->login($ftpUser, $ftpPasswd))
    {
       die("Failed to connect to SFTP server");
    }
    else
    {
       $sftp->put($filename,$b64Data);
       echo "Uploaded the file (".$filename.")\n";
    }
```

When I try to run this, I'm getting:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function crypt_random_string() in
>   /var/www/phpseclib0.3.5/Net/SSH2.php on line 1014

I've installed php5-mcrypt and phpseclib. Do I need to install any other dependencies for phpseclib? Please let me know.

Thanks much in advance,
Regards,
Sudheer

Answer (score 0):

crypt_string_random is defined in Crypt/Random.php:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/0.3.5/phpseclib/Crypt/Random.php

But then again Net_SSH2 auto-includes Crypt/Random.php:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/0.3.5/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php#L749

And Net_SFTP extends Net_SSH2:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/0.3.5/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php#L253

And Net_SSH2 does a require_once so if anything you should be getting some sort of "file not found" error, if you're getting an error at all, not a "function not defined" error..

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I checked the code you mentioned above. And thats the error I'm getting ! Its a 'function not defined' error and not a 'file not found' error. Really confused on why I'm seeing the function not defined error.

Comment: What if you put an `echo "this far x1<br>\r\n"` right before the `require_once` in Net/SSH2.php and a `echo "this far x2<br>\r\n"` right after ?

Comment: Tried that. Added this         echo "this far x1<br>\r\n";
        if (!function_exists('crypt_random_string')) {
            echo "this far x2<br>\r\n";
            require_once('Crypt/Random.php');
            echo "this far x3<br>\r\n";
        }
   And, here's the output I got   "this far x1<br>
this far x2<br>
this far x3<br>
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function crypt_random_string() in /var/www/phpseclib0.3.5/Net/SSH2.php on line 1017"

Comment: Can you add a "this far x4" to Crypt/Random.php? Like at the top of it before the function is defined?

Comment: Added as you mentioned. "this far x4" is not printed out, which means the 'Crypt/Random.php' is not getting included ?

Comment: That's what it's looking like. Maybe the permissions are off? Can you do `echo file_get_contents('Crypt/Random.php')`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by how PHP handles nested include statements and relative paths.  If you look at the current phpseclib programming, at least 'some' of the includes still use include() instead of require_once() which silently fail - which is why you don't see the errors about failing includes.

It all comes down to how PHP resolves relative pathing of nested includes - using the starting location of the parent script or the starting location of the current/child script. More info on the conundrum of PHP nested includes with relative pathing here:

[php nested include behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860143/php-nested-include-behavior)

When I ran into this problem myself, I worked around it by promoting /phpseclib out of it's own subfolder and into my existing /includes folder.  Then I only ever include phpseclib files from within php scripts in my /includes folder so that the relative paths in phpseclib's nested include statements will work.