# Why does PHP Include not work with child Includes?

Tags: php, html

I may have phrased the question slightly wrong so feel free to edit the title.

I was working on a site and I made this whole PHP Include system that was easy so that people with less knowledge could edit the content. Anyway it was like this.

Say you have index.php and the code is.

```
<?PHP
   include 'tabs.php';
?>
```

and then tabs.php is:

```
include 'tab-1.php'
```

2, 3 etc.

and then tab-1 is:

```
<?PHP
include 'tab-1-content.php'
?>
```

I hope you kind of get the idea, of course the formatting was way neater and there was html around it and stuff but the point is it didnt work at all. It seems like you can only include one file and then if there is an include in that file it wont work. I was wondering if anyone could explain this!?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [php nested include behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860143/php-nested-include-behavior)

Comment: No, you can include many, many files.... clearly there's something else wrong here, but there's not nearly enough information in your question to explain anything. Have you looked at your logs to see if any errors are being logged?

Comment: Provided that paths are OK, it must work. Make sure you always use PHP opening tag, for example you haven't put it in your code snippet of tabs.php.

Comment: `tabs.php` must also contain `<?php` tag (`?>` can be omitted in php-only files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think multiple includes doesn't cause problems ... but if it doesn't work for you, it's most probably you have a conflict in the files' paths.
My advice is to test the includes statements one by one for example:-

```
include 'tabs.php';
```

if the above line works fine, add into "tabs.php" the following line

```
include 'tab-1.php'
```

and keep going until you find the file where the problem happens.